# How can I send a Javascript variable to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php

```
 <script>
    function myHandler(){
    var idproduct = myHandler.caller.arguments[0].target.id;    
    document.getElementById("product").value = idproduct;
    }
 </script>


<input class="form-control" id="product" name="view"  type="text" disabled " />
        <?php $product_view = X ?>
```

Some one know what can I add on my javascript so I can send the variable "idproduct" to product_view variable

Comment: I am not going to vote this question down , but I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the two technologies.
I Highly recommend you look into some of the basics of web dev at places like codeschool

Answer (score 0):

Use a `form` and `Post` or `Get` You can also optionally use `WebSockets` or you can probably use a request to a .php page setup to handle such of another type of request.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a hidden field and then treat that in your post back or call back

Comment: man you have and idea how can I do it?

Comment: `<input type ="hidden" name="view" value="">` 

`$_POST['view']` or `$_GET['view']` depends how you send the form